# Can 2 IP's in the same network communicate with 2 different netmask

Tags: networking, subnet, ip-routing, netmask

I need to expand a network really quick and don't have time or access to change the netmask of all devices.

Can the following communicate?

IP 1 -  192.168.10.10 mask 255.255.255.0

IP 2 - 192.168.10.15 mask 255.255.0.0

Our switches we don't have the password or time to reset and reconfigure so we only want to change DHCP, servers and VPN. Please let me know if they will be able to communicated.

Comment: Those two IP adresses you listed are on the same network (192.168.10.X), so I really don't see what the problem is here?

Comment: They're not on the same network, based on the subnet masks listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

They can communicate... BUT... doing it this way is plain wrong. You will run in to problems with VPN'ed devices and will experience inconsistent behavior for anything outside the 192.168.10/24 network. You really need to find the time (I know, easy for me to say, I'm not where you are) to do it right - either change over all the devices, or just use a 192.168.11/24 network with an appropriate routing device joining it to the original 192.168.10/24 network.